# Problems in Apple Push Notifcation Service

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I am working on Apple Push Notification and I want to clarify few things.
1. Is Certificate signing request name and email should be on that person name which have Developer account on Apple Developer Portal, both account on same name and email??? because i am having Problem and i have different.
2. I made Provisioning Profile of app successfully but when i edited it, show status "Error", I again edited but same Prob, then I delete it and made again with same App Id then again it generated status Error, some one help me how to tackle this situation???

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, no they don't need to match up. It is advised that they do however.

I'm going to hope your second part is answered by now, but I would try creating a new app ID. Perhaps there is something funky going on, I've never had this issue and I've created a hand full of app IDs and provisioning profiles.